# Flutter - Unhandled exception

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I am learning flutter and I need so help / info regarding a weird behavior I'm experiencing.

```
Future<SharedPreferences> _preferences = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
final SharedPreferences preferences = await _preferences;
if (preferences.getString(USER_TOKEN_PREFERENCE) != '') {
  yield AuthentificationStatus.passed;
}
```

When the preferences are empty it's supposed to fire an Unhandled exception at the if line. Yet in debug on run the app is not crashing and the execution continues into the if statement.
When I evaluate in debug console an exception is indeed fired but if I wouldn't have noticed it if I hadn't checked...p

So why the execution is not stopping and the exception logged ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> execution is not stopping

because of your condition. if there is no data `preferences.getString(USER_TOKEN_PREFERENCE)` will return `null` and you check empty String in the condition. You should check

```
if (preferences.containsKey(USER_TOKEN_PREFERENCE) && preferences.getString(USER_TOKEN_PREFERENCE) != '') {
  yield AuthentificationStatus.passed;
}
```

or,

```
if (preferences.getString(USER_TOKEN_PREFERENCE) != null && preferences.getString(USER_TOKEN_PREFERENCE) != '') {
      yield AuthentificationStatus.passed;
    }
```

This [article](https://medium.com/flutterdevs/using-sharedpreferences-in-flutter-251755f07127) has a good example of SharedPreferences

Comment: Ok but it triggers an exception so why it's not detected by the debugger ?

Comment: your statement if (preferences.getString(USER_TOKEN_PREFERENCE) != '') is true, because Exception is not equal String.